# Justify text from right in two column springer document class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column, hyphenation

I am facing one problem in justifying text in springer document class. my code is as below

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
%\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{humannat}

\begin{document}

\title{Surface roughness analysis for PECVD, PVD and IBD for SiO$_{2}$ by various techniques}
\author{Muhammad Rizwan Amirzada \and author 2 \and author 3}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\justify
In this study, the comparison of surface roughness of SiO$_{2}$ thin layer which was 

deposited by PECVD, PVD and IBD process on glass, Si and PEN substrates will be presented.
\end{document}
```

The output of this code is shown below
[image]

you can clearly see that the 'h' in first row is totally misaligned from the other rows. This problem is in the whole document. Anyone can correct it ?

Thanks

Comment: just tried and it works like a charm.....thanks Werner :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issuing `\sloppy` in your preamble may allow for a more breathable flow of text in some cases, but also avoid<sup>*</sup> overfull boxes - typically the case when text overflows the text block/column margins. Fundamentally `\sloppy` gives an "emergency stretch" of `3em`, which should be plenty of space to have a word break at a "more appropriate" syllable.

<sub><sup>*</sup> [`source2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (p 311) mentions this about the definition of `\sloppy`: "`\sloppy` will never (well, hardly ever) produce overfull boxes, but may produce underfull ones. (14 June 85)"</sub>